# Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как выбросить свое исключение из одного метода и перехватить в другом

Tags: java

```
package main;

import exception.MyException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("file");
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line = bReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = bReader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (MyException e) {
            // code
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // code
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // code
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // code
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // code
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//созлаём свой класс и наследуем от Exception
class MyException extends Exception {
    //конструктор
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class Test {
    // сообщаем что метод бросает наше исключение
    static void method() throws MyException {
        if (true)//какое-то условие
            //какой-то код
            // и бросаем своё исключение
            throw new MyException("что-то пошло не так");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// оборачиваем наш метод в try catch
        try {
            method();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("словили");
        }

    }
}
```

вывод ->

```
.MyException: что-то пошло не так
    at starter.Test.method(Test.java:17)
    at starter.Test.main(Test.java:23)
словили
```